# How To Copy .mp4 File to clip board using win32clipboard?

Tags: python, clipboard

Below is a sample function code that want to convert to copy mp4 file to clipboard in python. Is there anyone to convert this code?

```
def send_to_clipboard(image):
    output = BytesIO()
    PIL.Image.open(image)
    image.convert('RGB').save(output, 'BMP')
    data = output.getvalue()[14:]
    output.close()

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: This code is for copying image file to clipboard but not for mp4 file to be copied into clipboard. let me edit above code to original one i have.

Comment: The code you've shown is for putting image data in the clipboard - like how you can copy an image from a browser and paste it straight into a chat program, for instance - but that's different than having a _file_ on the clipboard. I'm not aware of applications that allow you to copy video data itself to the clipboard - but of course you can easily copy a video _file_. By copying a file I mean like if you opened File Explorer and copied the file there. Which just essentially stores its path on the clipboard. Meaning any generic "store-file-on-clipboard" code should work for this.

Comment: i tried cmd commands from python subprocess to copy file using path, but no success, can you help me copy it via cmd command in subprocess using python? then we can paste it using win32clipboard anywhere in the code.

Comment: Notice how you used `CF_DIB` to declare the format of the contents of the clipboard?  You'll need to find a corresponding format for video.  I wouldn't assume the conversion from mp4 to that format will be as simple as the way you found for images.  And in fact since videos are so much larger than images, you might find it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't do that. Instead, this worked for me:

```
fullpath = 'C:\Users\Desktop\video.mp4'
os.system(f'powershell Set-Clipboard -Path {fullpath}')
```

then, paste.